# How can i move SVG Polygon element by mouse?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I want to move this polygon  by mouse. How can i do this?
I think i should use some like onMouseDown and onMouseMove get new position and transform="translate(x,y) but how can i do this by JS?

Comment: you can use `drag` event

Comment: Have a look at https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_ondrag.asp, might help. You can get cursor positions via the method

Answer (score 2):

You can use [draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/) from jquery UI. Here is your edited code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Title</title>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script>
  $( function() {
   $( "#Layer_1" ).draggable();
  } );
 </script>
</head>

<body>
 <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 500 500" style="enable-background:new 0 0 500 500;" xml:space="preserve">
  <polygon class="st0" points=" 0,5 10,0 20,5 10,10" transform="translate(90,95) rotate(0 0 0)" stroke="none" fill="red"/>
 </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks. but i have 2 points. i wanna drug it independently and line should connect points. Can you help with that?

http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=28wTfcIoa9

Comment: You can use different ids with draggable. Like `$( "#Layer_1, #Layer_2, #Layer_3" ).draggable();` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Take the reference from below, it's working:

**HTML:**

```
<svg id="pointer" height="50" width="50">
    <polygon points="1,1 49,10 20,20 10,49"> 
    <!-- coordinates are in x,y format -->
   <!-- points go clockwise around the polygon -->
</svg>
<a href="bbc.co.uk" target="_blank">bbc</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
#pointer {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 200px;
  left: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
html {
  cursor: none;
}
a {
  font-size: 40px;
}
a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
var mouseX;
var mouseY;
window.onmousemove = handleMouseMove;
function handleMouseMove(event) {
  event = event || window.event;
  document.getElementById('pointer').style.top=event.clientY + "px";
  document.getElementById('pointer').style.left=event.clientX + "px";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to extend the problem to **selecting objects inside an SVG, and then moving them by dragging**.

We will need a variable to record the currently selected element.
(`selectedElement`)

And handle the `svg.onclick` event to update the element we have selected.

Next, handle the `svg.onmousedown` event.

When this event is triggered, obtain the mouse coordinates.(`startX, startY = e.clientX, e.clientY`)

Then, add an event handler for `mousemove` inside it. Since we previously obtained the initial mouse position,

we only need to use the mousemove coordinate information together with the original coordinate information to determine the displacement relationship. (`dx, dy = e.clientX -startX, e.clientY - startY`)

This way, you can correctly obtain the offset data required for the [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform).

---

Here is a code demonstration:
(*pure JavaScript, without any other dependencies.*)

```html
<!--  Optional -->
<style>
  .selected {
    stroke-dasharray: 5, 5;
    stroke: red;
    stroke-width: 3;
  }
</style>

<!--  Optional -->
<label>transform<input type="radio" name="tool" value="transform" checked></label>
<label>OtherTool<input type="radio" name="tool" value="OtherTool"></label>

<svg width="100%" height="100%">

  <!--  for test only, you can put any component you like. -->
  <rect x="100" y="100" width="100" height="100" fill="blue"/>
  <circle cx="300" cy="300" r="50" fill="green"/>
  <line x1="50" y1="50" x2="450" y2="450" stroke="purple" stroke-width="3"/>
  <polygon points="68.5,50.59375 130.5,50.59375 107.5,89.59375 50.5,86.59375"></polygon>
</svg>


<script>
  const svg = document.querySelector("svg")
  let selectedElement = null

  svg.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const target = e.target

    if (selectedElement) {
      selectedElement.classList.remove('selected')
    }

    if (target.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'svg') {
      target.classList.add('selected')
      selectedElement = target
    } else {
      selectedElement = null
    }
  })

  svg.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
    if (!selectedElement) {
      return
    }

    // get mousedown info
    const startX = e.clientX
    const startY = e.clientY
    const match = selectedElement.style.transform.match(/translate\((-?\d+)px,\s*(-?\d+)px\)/)

    // and we are going to handle mousemove event
    let mousemoveHandler
    const tool = document.querySelector("input[name='tool']:checked").value
    switch (tool) {
      case "transform":
        mousemoveHandler = (e) => {
          const dx = e.clientX - startX
          const dy = e.clientY - startY
          if (match) {
            selectedElement.style.transform = `translate(${dx + Number(match[1])}px, ${dy + Number(match[2])}px)`
          } else {
            selectedElement.style.transform = `translate(${dx}px, ${dy}px)`
          }
        }
        break
    }

    const mouseupHandler = () => {
      document.removeEventListener('mousemove', mousemoveHandler)
      document.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseupHandler)
    }

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemoveHandler)
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseupHandler)
  })
</script>
```