# SVG and JavaScript: moving elements with mouse only moves elements down and to the right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

This code is supposed to let users move SVG elements around, but for some reason, the elements only move down and to the right independent of mouse movement.

Other questions [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47010682/how-can-i-move-svg-element-by-mouse) are similar but do not help.

Can you not mix `getBoundingClientRect` with manipulation of an element's `x` and `y` attributes?

Because the attributes may contain percentage values, we use `getBoundingClientRect` as ground truth for an element's position.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZVKvgp

```
var selectedElem = $("#imageBox1");
var isMoving = false;
var mouseLastX = null;
var mouseLastY = null;

$(document).bind('mousedown', function(e) {
   isMoving = true;
});

$(document).bind('mouseup', function(e) {
    isMoving = false;
    mouseLastX = null;
    mouseLastY = null;
});

$(document).bind('mousemove', function(event) {
     // Ignore if not moving
     if (!isMoving) {
        return;
     }

     // Exit if attempting to move, but no element is selected.
     if (!selectedElem) {
        console.log("Error moving element: no selected element.");
     }

     // If here, move selected element.
     // Get current mouse position.
     var mouseCurX = event.pageX;
     var mouseCurY = event.pageY;

     // Set last position? Must check null explicitly in case values are 0.
     if (mouseLastX == null || mouseLastY == null) {
        mouseLastX = mouseCurX;
        mouseLastY = mouseCurY;
     }

     // Get current values for selected element.
     var elemClientRect = selectedElem[0].getBoundingClientRect();
     var elemX = elemClientRect.x;
     var elemY = elemClientRect.y;

     // Set deltas.
     var deltaX = mouseCurX - mouseLastX;
     var deltaY = mouseCurY - mouseLastY;

     // Set new element position.
     var newX = elemX + deltaX;
     var newY = elemY + deltaY;

     // Store mouse position.
     mouseLastX = mouseCurX;
     mouseLastY = mouseCurY;

     // Update element.
     selectedElem.attr("x", newX);
     selectedElem.attr("y", newY);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues

1. `getBoundingClientRect` will give you `x` and `y` relative to the page, however the `x` and `y` attributes are relative to the parent container
2. The initial `x` and `y` attributes of `imageBox1` are both `25%`, so you can't just add pixels to that, you need to use the `calc(25% + << delta >>px)` format

Here's how to get the image to move the way you want:

```js
var selectedElem = $("#imageBox1");
var isMoving = false;
var mouseLastX = null;
var mouseLastY = null;

$(document).bind('mousedown', function(e) {
   isMoving = true;
});

$(document).bind('mouseup', function(e) {
    isMoving = false;
    mouseLastX = null;
    mouseLastY = null;
});

$(document).bind('mousemove', function(event) {
     // Ignore if not moving
     if (!isMoving) {
        return;
     }

     // Exit if attempting to move, but no element is selected.
     if (!selectedElem) {
        console.log("Error moving element: no selected element.");
     }

     // If here, move selected element.
     // Get current mouse position.
     var mouseCurX = event.pageX;
     var mouseCurY = event.pageY;
  
     // Set last position? Must check null explicitly in case values are 0.
     if (mouseLastX && mouseLastY) {

       // Get current values for selected element.
       var currX = selectedElem.attr("x");
       var currY = selectedElem.attr("y");
       var elemXpct = parseInt(currX.match(/\d+(?=%)/));
       var elemYpct = parseInt(currY.match(/\d+(?=%)/));
       var elemXpxls = parseInt(currX.match(/\d+(?=px)/) || 0) * (/-/.test(currX) ? -1 : 1);
       var elemYpxls = parseInt(currY.match(/\d+(?=px)/) || 0) * (/-/.test(currY) ? -1 : 1);

       // Set deltas.
       var deltaX = mouseCurX - mouseLastX;
       var deltaY = mouseCurY - mouseLastY;
       
       // Set new element position.
       var newX = elemXpxls + deltaX;
       var newY = elemYpxls + deltaY;
       
       var newXsign = newX < 0 ? '-' : '+';
       var newYsign = newY < 0 ? '-' : '+';
       
       // Update element.
       selectedElem.attr("x", `calc(${elemXpct}% ${newXsign} ${Math.abs(newX)}px)`);
       selectedElem.attr("y", `calc(${elemXpct}% ${newYsign} ${Math.abs(newY)}px)`);
     }
  
     // Store mouse position.
     mouseLastX = mouseCurX;
     mouseLastY = mouseCurY;

});
```

```css
.imageBox {
  cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg id="rootBox" width="375" height="812" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  
    <rect x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" fill="beige" />
  
    <svg id="imageBox1" class="imageBox" x="25%" y="25%" width="50%" height="50%">
       <image class="image" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/bzm1y7tjrhl872s/Screenshot.png?raw=1" />
       <image class="frame" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/6njspwfz2hgfd03/iPhone_X_Black.png?raw=1" />
    </svg>
    
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Random question, but have you implemented code to snap SVG elements to other elements and show smart guides while the user moves elements around?

Comment: BTW do you do SVG consulting?

Comment: @ic3b3rg Dragging the mouse does not work in Firefox

Answer (score 0):

If the objective is just to make SVG movable, you can use draggable from jquery.

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>`

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>`

`<script>
        $(function () {
            $("#draggable").draggable();
        });
 </script>`

and your html

`<svg id="draggable" width="375" height="812" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <rect x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" fill="beige" />
  <svg id="imageBox1" class="imageBox" x="25%" y="25%" width="50%" height="50%">
   <image class="image" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/bzm1y7tjrhl872s/Screenshot.png?raw=1" />
    <image class="frame" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/6njspwfz2hgfd03/iPhone_X_Black.png?raw=1" />
        </svg>
    </svg>`