# SVG element follow the cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, pointers, svg

can anyone help me with this?
I'm struggling with the "pupil" element that doesn't follow with precision the pointer. What I would like to do is similar to the reference linked below.

[Here is the Codepen I'm working on](https://codepen.io/giulioiamnot/pen/vYKrMRV)

[Here is the reference I'm trying to follow](https://codepen.io/GabEsu/pen/VdKjPE)

Every support and tip is welcome, thanks to all.

```js
let eyeBall = document.querySelector(".eyeball"),
    pupil = document.querySelector(".pupil"),
    eyeArea = eyeBall.getBoundingClientRect(),
    pupilArea = pupil.getBoundingClientRect(),
    R = eyeArea.width/2,
    r = pupilArea.width/2,
    centerX = eyeArea.left + R,
    centerY = eyeArea.top + R;

document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e)=>{
  let x = e.clientX - centerX,
      y = e.clientY - centerY,
      theta = Math.atan2(y,x),
      angle = theta*180/Math.PI + 360;
  
  
  pupil.style.transform = `translateX(${R - r +"px"}) rotate(${angle + "deg"})`;
  pupil.style.transformOrigin = `${r +"px"} right`;
});
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height:100vh;
}
.eye{
  margin: auto;
/*   background:#ccc; */
}


.pupil {
  position:relative;
/*   transform:  rotate(390deg); */
/*   transform-origin: 20px center; */
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Livello_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
     viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1000 1000;" xml:space="preserve" height="400px" class="eye">
<g>
    
  <circle cx="499.52" cy="338.428" r="230" fill="yellow" class="eyeball" />
  
  <circle cx="499.52" cy="338.428" r="170.306" class="pupil" />
  
    
  
</g>
  
<path d="M728.777,19.651v70.071C668.44,34.06,587.887,0,499.52,0C312.911,0,161.092,151.819,161.092,338.428
    S312.911,676.856,499.52,676.856c88.368,0,168.92-34.06,229.258-89.722V890.83H311.747V1000h526.201V19.651H728.777z
     M499.52,567.686c-126.412,0-229.258-102.846-229.258-229.258S373.108,109.17,499.52,109.17s229.258,102.846,229.258,229.258
    S625.931,567.686,499.52,567.686z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: You need a diferent way to detect the mouse position in SVG Please check the  oMousePos function here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54158088/move-dynamically-created-svg-with-mouse